# Office365 Authentication: getting user email from access token

Tags: python, django, authentication, office365

I am using python and django for my web application, and I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API for user sign in authentication to my app using their office365 credentials.  I've read up on examples on the web and have been able to successfully get an authorization code and an access token. However I am not able to get a valid response from my GET API call, and get_me function.  I keep getting a 500 error. I am using in my scopes openid, profile, and email. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong

Comment: Please post copy-paste-able snippets. It is easier to run it yourself and see what is wrong for the community to be able to help, and does not take long.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is posting screenshots of code. Don't do that.

Comment: You should create a [mcve] or it will be unlikely your question gets answered.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  I apologize, I am in my first year of programming and this is my first ever post on this site.

Answer (score 0):

[`pythoncontacts`](https://github.com/jasonjoh/pythoncontacts) ties Django and Office 365 together and Microsoft provides an [example of connecting to the Graph API via Python](https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/5989).

Answer (score 0):

The scopes you list won't be enough to actually make any API calls. Those scopes will get you an ID token and refresh token in the response, but that's it. To call API calls, you need to add the required scope (depending on what API calls you want to make).

If you're trying to call the Graph endpoint (https://graph.microsoft.com/) then, for example, if you want to just read the user's email, you can add `Mail.Read` to the scope array.

If you find the API call you want to make at https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs, it should list what scope is required.